# Accessing multiple Editboxes in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I am writing a MFC program in which I have a a lot of Editboxes and I want to get all their text values and put them in a container. How can I achieve this without writing a line for each ID. I'm using this code for each ID: 
    `CEdit *edit;` 
    `edit = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_NAME1));`
But if I use that method I would have to write it 45 times. That doesn't seem right.
Is there a way of getting all the Editboxes in a container so I can use them that way or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly create an array (or other container) or pointers to CEdit: `CEdit edits[45];` If the values of `IDC_NAME1` through `IDC_NAME45` are contiguous, you can just do something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<45; i++)
   names[i] = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_NAME1 + i));
```

If those identifiers may not be contiguous, then you can put them in an array, and just index into that array as needed.

One caution: unless they're something like a grid of otherwise nearly identical edit controls, 45 on a screen may well be a bit much. If they are like a grid, you might want to look at one of the many available grid controls instead.

Comment: @IliyanLaskov IDC_NAME1+1 != IDC_NAME2 as IDs, of course, but if IDC_NAME1 is 200 and IDC_NAME2 is 201, it is true. You have to make sure that the IDs are contiguous and in the right order. Check your resource.h file

Comment: Now I understand what IDC_NAME1+1 meant. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use controls IDs.
Use EnumChildWindows and get test only for edit controls. Snippet follows.

---

Add following in dialog’s header:

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnFoundEdit(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

And this to cpp:

```
#define WM_U_FOUND_EDIT WM_APP + 0x100


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEditCtrlFishingDlg, CDialog)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_U_FOUND_EDIT, OnFoundEdit)
    .
    .
    .
    .
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Write this line in the place you want to start edit text collection:

```
    EnumChildWindows(m_hWnd, EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)m_hWnd);
```

Enum child procedure:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CString csBuffer;
    LPTSTR pBuf = csBuffer.GetBufferSetLength(MAX_PATH);
    GetClassName(hwnd, pBuf, MAX_PATH);
    csBuffer.ReleaseBuffer();

    if(!csBuffer.CompareNoCase(_T("edit")))
    {
        SendMessage((HWND)lParam, WM_U_FOUND_EDIT, 0, (LPARAM)hwnd);
    }

    return TRUE;

}
```

and the handler:

```
LRESULT YourDlg::OnFoundEdit(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CWnd *pWnd = FromHandle((HWND)lParam);
    CString csTxt;

    pWnd->GetWindowText(csTxt);
    // do what you need with text here

    return 0;
}
```